# Appending list items

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a list of some length(let's say 1000). Each element of the list is another list of length = 2. Each element of the new list is a data.table. The second element of each list might be an empty data.table.

I need to rbind() all the data.frames that are in the first position of the list. I am currently doing the following:

```
DT1 = data.table()
DT2 = data.table()
for (i in 1:length(myList)){
     DT1 = rbind(DT1, myList[[i]][[1]]
     DT2 = rbind(DT2, myList[[i]][[2]]
}
```

This works, but it is too slow. Is there a way I can avoid the for-loop?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Even if you can avoid the for-loop it'll be slow as you are growing dataframes with `rbind` extensively.

Comment: `rbindlist(lapply(mylist, \`[[\`, 1L))`?

Comment: Thank you very much, this works faster than all the other suggestions! Please post it, so I can "accept" your answer.

Answer (score 2):

data table has a dedicated fast function: `rbindlist`
Cf: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/rbindlist

Edited:

Here is an example of code

```
 library(data.table)            
srcList=list(list(DT1=data.table(X=0),DT2=NULL),list(DT1=data.table(X=2),data.table(Y=3)))
# first have a list for all DT1s
DT1.list= lapply(srcList, FUN=function(el){el$DT1})
rbindlist(DT1.list)

   X
1: 0
2: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I saw the function, but I do not quite understand how it can be applied to bind to a list of lists

Comment: To be combined with a way to select suitable DT for instance with `lapply(myLisr, FUN=function(el) el[[1]])` to create DT1

Comment: Done. This would have been easier if we had already a definition for toy data.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(df.list, "[[", 1)) # for first list element

  # x  y
# 1 1 10
# 2 2 20
# 3 3 30
# 4 4 40
# 5 5 50
# 6 6 60

do.call("rbind", lapply(df.list, "[[", 2)) # for second list element

  # x  y
# 1 1 30
# 2 2 40
# 3 3 50
# 4 4 70
# 5 5 80
# 6 6 90
```

**DATA**

```
df.list=list(list(structure(list(x = 1:3, y = c(10, 20, 30)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    x = 1:3, y = c(30, 40, 50)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), list(structure(list(x = 4:6, y = c(40, 
50, 60)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(x = 4:6, y = c(70, 80, 90)), .Names = c("x", 
    "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")))

# df.list

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
  # x  y
# 1 1 10
# 2 2 20
# 3 3 30

# [[1]][[2]]
  # x  y
# 1 1 30
# 2 2 40
# 3 3 50


# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
  # x  y
# 1 4 40
# 2 5 50
# 3 6 60

# [[2]][[2]]
  # x  y
# 1 4 70
# 2 5 80
# 3 6 90
```

Comment: Thank you for posting such an informative and detailed reply!

Comment: @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos you may just vote up instead of giving thanks! :-)

Comment: I did, but due to low reputation it cannot show yet.